# In SICP exercise 2.26 using DrScheme, why does cons return a list, instead of a pair of lists?

Tags: scheme, sicp

In SICP exercise 2.26, this Scheme code is given:

```
(define x (list 1 2 3))
(define y (list 4 5 6))
```

Then this cons call is given:

```
(cons x y)
```

I expected a pair of lists would result, `((1 2 3) (4 5 6))` but the interpreter gives,
`((1 2 3) 4 5 6)`
...a list with 4 elements, the first being a list. Why is y treated differently?  I've tried looking up other SICP answers for an explanation, but couldn't find something satisfactory.  So could any Scheme/Lisp experts please shed some light on this aspect of cons?  Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: Thank you to all responders to my question, particularly Nathan and tonio.  This newbie in Scheme/Lisp now groks the language a bit better because of your detailed answers.

Comment: Also see [Recursive range in Lisp adds a period?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16379657/1281433) for a similar explanation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`'((1 2 3) 4 5 6)` is actually a pair of lists. Here's another way to write it:

```
'((1 2 3) . (4 5 6))
```

However, the printer avoids dotted pair notation whenever it can, so you get the first representation instead. The rule is:

```
'(x . (xs ...))
=>
'(x xs ...)
```

For any `x` and `xs`. Here, your `x = '(1 2 3)` and `xs = '(4 5 6)`, so you get `((1 2 3) 4 5 6)`.

---

To see how cons and dotted-pair notation is related, let's shorten the problem to just `'(1)` and `'(6)`. The lowest level way to build a pair of them is this:

```
(cons (cons 1 '()) (cons 6 '()))
```

Here, `'()` is nil, or the empty list. If we translate this literally to dotted-pair notation, we get this:

```
'((1 . ()) . (6 . ()))
```

But because the printer collapses dotted-pair notation whenever possible, you get this instead:

```
'((1 . ()) . (6 . ()))
=>
'((1) . (6))    ; <-- x=1, xs=nothing; x=6, xs=nothing
=>
'((1) 6) ; <-- x=1, xs=6
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation; I now see that it's a pair of lists, per the collapse of dotted pair notation, and since (cdr (cons x y)) gives the second list.  But why does (length (cons x y)) answer 4?  Shouldn't it be either 6 (count all elements of both lists), or 2 (count two lists)?

Comment: Ah, never mind my comment; I see it's a consequence of the (length) function they give in the book that doesn't deal with nested lists.

Comment: @limist: Well, sort of. Your problem (I think) is thinking of List as an opaque, separate data type. It's really just a convention of how to use cons pairs (see tonio's answer). So, to get length 6, you'd write `nested-list`, although this would really be called `tree-size` because it uses the tree convention for conses. On the other hand, to get 2 from `(length (cons '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))`, you'd have to get 2 for *any* list. That method ignores the list convention that says that, eg, '(1) is actually `(cons 1 '())`. Its length is 1, not 2, because of the way lists are constructed.

Comment: you're correct in your diagnosis, thank you. :)  I realized there was vagueness in my mind about how cons and list are defined when I worked through another SICP problem, and also, some "legacy" mental model from how lists work in python.  Thanks again for taking the time to explain things clearly, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 11):

`cons` uses the first argument as head of the list, and the second as tail.

You give it a first list `(1 2 3)`, which will constitute the head of the resulting list and a second list `(4 5 6)`, to be used as tail of the list. Thus, you end with `((1 2 3) 4 5 6)`.

Thing of lists as left-to-right combs, ending with empty list (represented as `o` here), and see how they combine.

```
 X=      Y=
 /\      /\
1 /\  + 4 /\    
 2 /\    5 /\  
  3  o    6  o
```

You then build:

```
 /\
X  Y
```

Obtaining:

```
  /\
 /\ \
1 /\ \
 2 /\ \
  3  o/\
     4 /\
      5 /\
       6  o
```

which is `((1 2 3) 4 5 6` when represented with parenthesis. And this is a pair of lists.

Comment: Yes, I tried to simplify the drawing a bit, but that was not really a success. Will try to improve this.

Comment: Thank you for the diagram explanation, it makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

hey, i think you could think of it in this way;

whenever there is a nil, there must be a pair of parenthesis, as follow:

(cons 1 (cons 2 nil))--> (list 1 2)

(let ((x (list 1 2 3)) (y (list 4 5 6))))

1.(cons x y)--> (cons   (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 nil)))   (cons 4 (cons 5 (cons 6 nil))))
here, the first nil stands for an end of a pair which could be expressed by parenthesis; whereas the second nil stands for the end of the whole pair which use another pair of parenthesis; 
so, ((1 2 3) 4 5 6)

2.(list x y)-> (cons x (cons y nil);
as we know the x contain a nil, so it must be (1 2 3); the second part contains two nils,
so ((1 2 3) (4 5 6));

the inner most nil means the outer most parenthesis;

Hope it can help.

Answer (score 1):

I found the diagrams in the [Emacs Lisp tutorial](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/html_node/Lists-diagrammed.html#Lists-diagrammed) particularly helpful when learning Lisp.

Answer (score 0):

Read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons

Answer (score 0):

try (list x y)
I'm sure it works on common lisp, I don't know about Scheme