# Why does using cons to create a pair of two lists produce a list and two elements?

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket

I've started learning Scheme, for fun mostly, and because I've never used a functional language before. I chose Scheme because I wanted to read [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) for a long time.

Anyway, I'm currently learning about lists, and before that I learned about cons, car and cdr.  And there's an example that creates a list of lists with cons, like this :

```
(cons (list 1 2) (list 3 4))
```

The resulting list is ((1 2) 3 4), which doesn't make sense to me, I would expect ((1 2)(3 4)) to be the result (a list made out of two lists). Why does it behave like that? I realize that if I were to use car, I would get (1 2), and cdr I'd get (3 4) becaue cdr always returns "the rest", but I don't understand why the list isn't made of two lists?

Comment: This question is slightly different, but the answers precisely answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921912/in-sicp-exercise-2-26-using-drscheme-why-does-cons-return-a-list-instead-of-a-p

Comment: why would you make a list with CONS when you earlier made a list with LIST? Why not stick with using LIST for making lists? CONS does not do the same as LIST - that's also why they are different functions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You get a list with `(1 2)` as the first element (the car) and `(3 4)` as the rest (the cdr) because the first argument to cons is the first element of the list and the second argument is a list containing the remaining items.

This closely resembles the structure of a list: each node of a (proper) list contains an element and a list containing all other element. `cons` creates one such node.

If the second argument to `cons` would become the second element of the list, how would you create a list with three arguments? You'd have to make `cons` variardic at which point, it'd just be another name for `list`.

If you want to create a list of lists use `(list (list 1 2) (list 3 4))`.

Comment: `(1 2)` is the car, not the cdr, and `(3 4)` is the cdr.

Answer (score 4):

```
(list (list 1 2)
      (list 3 4))
```

is the same as

```
(cons (list 1 2)
      (cons (list 3 4)
            '()))
```

Which results in

```
((1 2) (3 4))
```

which can also be written as

```
((1 . (2 . ()))
 . 
 ((3 . (4 . ()))
  .
  ()))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list A:  [  |      ]
          1   [ | ]
               2 /

list B:  [  |      ]
          3   [ | ]
               4 /

======================

(cons A B)

[           |           ]
 [  |     ]   [  |     ]
  1  [ | ]     3  [ | ]
      2 /          4 /
```

A graphic representation of the inner structures can help us to visualize the problem.

And this will help some more:

```
[           |           ]
     X        [  |     ]
               3  [ | ]
                   4 /
```

Do you see the pattern? The above is the list `(X 3 4)`. That's the reason `(cons A B)` draws only the `car` part as a separate list and not the `cdr`.

Answer (score 2):

Because a cons-cell is *not* a list of two elements, the two are often confused. If `(a . b)` is a cons cell, then `(a . (b . ()))` is a list of two elements. Any list - save the empty list specifically - is a cons cell whose `car` field contains the first element and whose `cdr` field contains the list which contains the remaining elements. A list is thus simply a binary tree whose right-most leaf is the special constant `()` or `nil` depending on your dialect.

Which is why `(cons 0 '(1 2 3))` evaluates to `(0 1 2 3)` and not `(0 (1 2 3))`: we create a `cons` cell whose `car` is `0`, and whose `cdr` is `(1 2 3)`, so, a list `(0 1 2 3)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really simple explanation:

```
(define (x)
(cons (list 1 2) (list 3 4)))
```

we know that these two conditions must be true:

```
(car x) = (1 2) #car = first element
(cdr x) = (3 4) #cdr = rest of the elements
```

the only way to satisfy this is `x = ((1 2) 3 4)`.
**________________________________________________________________________________________________________**

`x = ((1 2)(3 4))` is incorrect because:

```
(car x) = (1 2)
(cdr x) = ((3 4))
```

See there is an extra bracket/list created for `(cdr x)`.

`x = ((1 2)(3 4))` is actually a list of lists:

```
list( list(1 2) list(3 4)) = ((1 2)(3 4))
```