# How does ruby handle array range accessing?

Tags: ruby, arrays, range

```
ruby-1.8.7-p174 > [0,1][2..3]
 => [] 
ruby-1.8.7-p174 > [0,1][3..4]
 => nil
```

In a 0-index setting where index 2, 3, and 4 are all in fact out of bounds of the 2-item array, why would these return different values?

Comment: Your question has less noise, but unfortunately: possible duplicate of [Array slicing in Ruby: looking for explanation for illogical behaviour (taken from Rubykoans.com)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568222/array-slicing-in-ruby-looking-for-explanation-for-illogical-behaviour-taken-fr). In both cases the surprise is the same: nil vs [] at the end index.

Comment: Wow, duplicate declined. Why?

Comment: Good question. I raised a flag to ask to reevaluate or explain. I am curious to learn the reasoning of such.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is a known ugly odd corner. Take a look at the examples in rdoc for [Array#slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-slice).

This specific issue is listed as a "special case"

```
   a = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" ]
   a[2] +  a[0] + a[1]    #=> "cab"
   a[6]                   #=> nil
   a[1, 2]                #=> [ "b", "c" ]
   a[1..3]                #=> [ "b", "c", "d" ]
   a[4..7]                #=> [ "e" ]
   a[6..10]               #=> nil
   a[-3, 3]               #=> [ "c", "d", "e" ]
   # special cases
   a[5]                   #=> nil
   a[5, 1]                #=> []
   a[5..10]               #=> []
```

If the start is *exactly* one item beyond the end of the array, then it will return `[]`, an empty array. If the start is beyond that, `nil`. It's documented, though I'm not sure of the reason for it.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3568281/) and related comments where the difference is described in terms of 'fence-posting' and 'indexing'. I do agree with Ciro, this question is a duplicate. For those reading this Q&A, be aware that more details exist on the 'why' in that duplicate.