# Slice an Array in half at a given index, but leaving out the index

Tags: arrays, ruby, slice

Given an array

```
x = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

I'd like to slice it in half at a certain point/index and create two subarrays of such cut, but leaving out the index.
Example:

```
x = [2, 3, 4, 6, 70, 10]
left, right = x.slice_at_index(2)
left  = [2, 3]
right = [6, 70, 10]
```

I've tried with `each_index`, slice, chunk but can't leave out the index element.

Answer (score 3):

```
left, right = x.take(index), x.drop(index.next)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
left = x[0..1]
right = x[3..-1]
```

Comment: He is saying " leaving out the index". The value at index should not be present at the result array.

Answer (score 1):

I think, docs like about [array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html) should help you next time.

So, **UPD** solution for you:

```
x = [2, 3, 4, 6, 70, 10]
left, right = x.shift(2), x.drop(2.pred)

> left
=> [2, 3]
> right
=> [6, 70, 10]
```

Comment: That's a Good one!

Comment: This doesn't leave the element @ index as OP wanted. It also mutates `x`, which is horrific.

Comment: Worked like a charm!.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method:

```
def slice_at_index(array, index)
  left = array[0...index]  # 3 dots vs 2
  right = array[(index + 1)..-1]
  return [left, right]
end
```

But, I would generally avoid multiple assignment such as `left, right = slice_at_index(x, 2)` as a style rule.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, and I think most readable, is to use the range operator `..` to specify the indexes you want out of the array.

```
def slice_at(array, index)
  left = array[0..(index - 1)]
  right = array[(index + 1)..-1]
  return [left, right]
end
```

---

If you'd like to learn more about how the range operator works when used this way, read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947002/how-does-ruby-handle-array-range-accessing).

Remember that you can use `...` or `..` in Ruby to generate ranges. Using three dots will include the starting point, but exclude the ending point, while using two dots will include both the starting and ending points. See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690801/difference-between-double-dot-and-triple-dot-in-range-generation).