# Ruby Array Indicies

Tags: ruby, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Array slicing in Ruby: looking for explanation for illogical behaviour (taken from Rubykoans.com)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568222/array-slicing-in-ruby-looking-for-explanation-for-illogical-behaviour-taken-fro)

Running this code on my ruby interpreter it ends up with 7..4 outputting nil, and 6..4 outputting nothing

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

p arr[7..4]
p arr[6..4]
```

According to the ruby doc if the initial index is out of range it returns a nil, and in this case both (6 & 7) are out of range of the array, but only the first returns a nil.

Edit for clairification: The output is as follows:

```
nil 
[]
```

Why would the first return nil and the second []?

Comment: It's not a duplicate. In this question we have `..` instead of `,` and reversed borders.

Comment: @Nakilon: There's no difference, what matters is the first index. @Paul: You should change `puts` with `p`, to avoid confusion about what's the result of the slicing, and what's the result of `puts` itself.

Comment: OK, I've reread, really, duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Well, probably the interpreter doesn't understand the range "decreasing", trying

```
puts arr[3..1]
```

also returned nothing, maybe because `[3..1]` is not a range. 
[]s

Comment: Thats kind of the problem, on one it returns empty [], the other returns the value nil. They SHOULD both either return nil or return [], not one doing nil and one []. This is on 1.8.7 on osx if it makes a difference.

Comment: Slicing an array using an "inverted" range is usual in Ruby: for example: `[1,2,3,4][1..-2]` gives `[2, 3]`.

Comment: lol , I don't knew. Nice! Thanks @Mladen