# Why does this array slice return an empty array instead of nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Array slicing in Ruby: looking for explanation for illogical behaviour (taken from Rubykoans.com)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568222/array-slicing-in-ruby-looking-for-explanation-for-illogical-behaviour-taken-fro)

I've been playing around with array slicing in ruby but I don't understand the last 2 results below:

```
a = [1,2,3]
a[2,1]      # output is [3]
a[3,1]      # output is []    ...why??
a[4,1]      # output is nil   ...according to the docs this makes sense
```

Why would `a[3,1]` be an empty array while `a[4,1]` is nil?

If anything, I would expect `a[3,1]` to return nil as well. According to the [ruby docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html) an array split should return nil if the start index is out of range. So why is it that `a[3,1]` is not returning nil?

Note: This is on ruby 1.9.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're asking for the end of the array, which is `[]`. Look at it this way: the Array `[1,2,3]` can be considered to be constructed from cons cells as such: `(1, (2, (3, ()))`, or `1:2:3:[]`. The 3rd index (4th item) is then clearly `[]`.

Answer (score 2):

" Returns nil if the index (or starting index) are out of range."

`a[3,1]` is a special case according to the example in the same link.

more info can be seen here by the way: [Array slicing in Ruby: looking for explanation for illogical behaviour (taken from Rubykoans.com)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568222/array-slicing-in-ruby-looking-for-explanation-for-illogical-behaviour-taken-fro)

Comment: oh wait hmmm yeah that is strange lol

Comment: hehe yeah. Doing a[3] returns nil so I know it's out of range.

Comment: it does have the same example as yours, look at a[5,1], also returns empty array

Comment: I'm using 1.9.2 and for a[5,1] I get nil.

Comment: it says that it is a special case apparently. using a[a.size,1] will return an empty array

Comment: +1 for the good link. Some answers there were convincing.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to understand why if you imagine the slice on the *left* side of an assignment.

```
>> (b = a.clone)[2,1] = :a; p b
[1, 2, :a]
>> (b = a.clone)[2,0] = :b; p b
[1, 2, :b, 3]
>> (b = a.clone)[3,1] = :c; p b
[1, 2, 3, :c]
>> (b = a.clone)[3,0] = :d; p b
[1, 2, 3, :d]
```

Comment: Is this just an alternate way to push to the array?

Comment: do you know of a situation when something like this would be useful? Right now I'm more curious about the WHY than the HOW.