# Confusion about ruby Array [] method results when starting index greater than (array.size -1)

Tags: ruby, arrays, null, slice

Given

```
array = [:a,:b,:c,:d] # with 4 elements:

array[3] => :d  # zero-based indices, I get that
array[4] => nil
array[5] => nil

array[3,0] => [] # OK since I asked for a slice with zero elements
```

Doco for array[start,length] says that it *"Returns nil if the index (or starting index) are out of range."*

```
array[5,0] => nil # OK
array[4,0] => []  # Hunh??
```

How `come array[4,0]` returns an array as opposed to `nil`?

[edit] Looks like this has already come up: see [Array slicing in Ruby: looking for explanation for illogical behaviour (taken from Rubykoans.com)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568222/array-slicing-in-ruby-looking-for-explanation-for-illogical-behaviour-taken-fro)

To me the explanation looks a bit like hand waving, but I'll settle for it and just accept that ruby violates PLS here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array slicing in Ruby: looking for explanation for illogical behaviour (taken from Rubykoans.com)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568222/array-slicing-in-ruby-looking-for-explanation-for-illogical-behaviour-taken-fro)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the documentation does not word the behavior correctly. But intuitively, the bahavior makes sense. Just like it is possible to define a 0-element "sliver" at the beginning of the array, before all elements by indexing `array[0,0]`, it should also be possible, symmetrically, to get a 0-element "sliver" at the end of the array, after all the elements, by indexing `array[array.size,0]`. Another example would be that it should intuitively always be possible to get a copy of an array by indexing over its whole range, i.e. `array[0,array.size]`; but this would not be possible for empty arrays if we returned nil when the starting index is equal to the array size.