# Unexpected behavior of Ruby Array?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Array slicing in Ruby: looking for explanation for illogical behaviour (taken from Rubykoans.com)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568222/array-slicing-in-ruby-looking-for-explanation-for-illogical-behaviour-taken-fro)

I have an Array 'a'

```
a = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" ]
```

In irb i have done following experiment

```
irb(main):003:0> a[4,1]
=> ["e"]
irb(main):004:0> a[5,1]
=> []
irb(main):005:0> a[6,1]
=> nil
irb(main):006:0>
```

My question is,

in case of a[5,1] why it return an empty array instead of 'nil'?
is this behavior expected? if so why?

In  [Ruby doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000267) it is marked as '# special cases',
Unfortunately, they are not explained why it works this way?

I have notice same problem and also solution in two place of Stack overflow, [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568222/array-slicing-in-ruby-looking-for-explanation-for-illogical-behaviour-taken-fro) and [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919287/ruby-arraystart-length-not-co-operating)
In first one it is explained as 'slice does not identify the element but places between elements'

In second one it is explained as a bug of ruby implementation.

what will be proper explanation of this problem?