# Why does a Ruby array allow access to invalid range index?

Tags: ruby, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Array slicing in Ruby: looking for explanation for illogical behaviour (taken from Rubykoans.com)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568222/array-slicing-in-ruby-looking-for-explanation-for-illogical-behaviour-taken-fr)

In one of the Ruby koans, there's the following problem:

```
def test_slicing_arrays
  array = [:peanut, :butter, :and, :jelly]

  assert_equal _, array[0,1]
  assert_equal _, array[0,2]
  assert_equal _, array[2,2]
  assert_equal _, array[2,20]
  assert_equal _, array[4,0]
  assert_equal _, array[4,100]
  assert_equal _, array[5,0]
end
```

You must fill in the _ with the correct statement. The first four asserts work how I'd expect them to, but I'm confused about the last three.

`array[4,0]` gives back `[]`, as does `array[4,100]`. At this point I figured that ranges outside of the array (greater than 3 in this case) simply return an empty array.

But `array[5,0]` returns `nil` which has now confused me completely.

Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568222/array-slicing-in-ruby-looking-for-explanation-for-illogical-behaviour-taken-fr

Comment: Wish I had found that question when searching – thanks.

Comment: It was the second on the list of related questions that stackoverflow provided when you entered the question (see the right sidebar of the page). Anyway, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby is not a static language, forcing you to pre-declare the size of the array. It expands arrays as you assign to a particular element.

Normally we'd append to the end of the array:

```
array = []       # => []
array << 1       # => [1]
array += [2]     # => [1, 2]
array.push(3)    # => [1, 2, 3]
```

Or push onto the front of it:

```
array.unshift(0) # => [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

to add elements, which keeps the array accumulating the values without gaps.

We can do it randomly too, which can be useful:

```
array[10] = 10 # => 10
array          # => [0, 1, 2, 3, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, 10]
```

And that's what you've encountered.

---

You can predefine the array to a size, but it remains dynamic:

```
ary = Array.new(10, nil) # => [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
ary[0] = 0               # => 0
ary[10] = 10             # => 10
ary                      # => [0, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, 10]
ary[12]=12               # => 12
ary                      # => [0, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, 10, nil, 12]
```

Comment: In addition to this: when stricter behaviour is desired, use [fetch](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-fetch).It can return an error (or a default value, or the result of a block) if the index lies outside the array.

Comment: With all due respect, this doesn't answer the question with the clarity a ruby beginner needs. The [top answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3568281/26737) to the duplicate question is much clearer.

Comment: It appears to answer the question to the satisfaction of the person ASKING the question. That is the unit of measure here.