# Ruby 1.9.3p125 Array#slice weird behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Array slicing in Ruby: looking for explanation for illogical behaviour (taken from Rubykoans.com)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568222/array-slicing-in-ruby-looking-for-explanation-for-illogical-behaviour-taken-fr)

Say you have an array

```
a = [1,2,3]
```

why the `a.slice(3,6)` returns `[]` while the `a.slice(4,6)` returns `nil`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Because it makes assignment more general

The mechanism is designed this way so slices can work in a highly generalized way on the left-hand side of assignment operators.

It doesn't really matter for `#slice` exactly because that result cannot be assigned but the same interpretation applies to `x[3, 6]` and those expressions *can* be assigned.

It's best to look at the array indices as identifying the spaces between elements, rather than the elements themselves.

This interpretation creates a consistent and useful interface ... for example, code can be written that will handle replacing elements or appending to zero length or populated Arrays, and all without needing special-case tests.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation lists special cases for when the start index equal to the length of the array:

```
a = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" ]

# special cases
a[5, 1]                #=> []
a[5..10]               #=> []
```

from: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-slice

So this appears to be the built-in functionality, since the start index is the length of the array the slice method is supposed to return an `[]`, but when you pass the length of the array you get `nil`. This is probably due to how Ruby is defining ranges within an array.

Comment: Your answer is correct but this doesn't mean the same for the behaviour of `slice`. `slice` should literally slice (if we want to name it that way) the array, starting from the first_index and ending at the second_index, and thus returning nothing (which is `nil` in Ruby) in both cases.

Comment: if an empty array was the same as nil, then the behavior above wouldn't have happened.

Comment: Yes, it's built-in functionality, but the OP seemed to be asking "Why?" and the answer is: *to generalize assignment.*