# Ruby arrays slice, can't understand this simple code snippet

Tags: ruby, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Array slicing in Ruby: looking for explanation for illogical behaviour (taken from Rubykoans.com)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568222/array-slicing-in-ruby-looking-for-explanation-for-illogical-behaviour-taken-fr)

I have a simple array object:

```
array = [:peanut, :butter, :and, :jelly]
```

Its length is, clearly, 4!

Now, take a look at these statements:

```
array[4,0] == []
array[5,0] == nil
```

Slicing the array from 4th index, it returns an empty array, but starting from 5th element, it returns nil. Why this happens?

Comment: found the answer, thanks! But I don't like it :)

Answer (score 1):

`slice(start, length)` (which is the method called when you access `array[]`) returns an array of length `length` starting at index `start`. This explains why `array[4,0]` return `[]`.

However, there is a corner case in this method. [The Ruby documentation of slice](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-slice) says:

> Returns nil if the index (or starting index) are out of range.

In your second example, `5` is out of range for `array`. This causes the method to return `nil`.

Comment: Yes, but 4 is out of range too. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For a second, I thought you had found a bug, but I think I can explain this behaviour. The starting index you give to `slice` is considered just **before** the element at that index. So index `4` is considered the very **end** of the array (just before index `4`, just after index `3`). The following examples should make it clear:

```rb
> [1,2,3,4][0, 3]
 # => [1, 2, 3] 
> [1,2,3,4][1, 3]
 # => [2, 3, 4] 
> [1,2,3,4][2, 3]
 # => [3, 4] 
> [1,2,3,4][3, 3]
 # => [4] 
> [1,2,3,4][4, 3]
 # => [] 
> [1,2,3,4][5, 3]
 # => nil
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the reason for things you found "strange" should always lie in source code. I just pick the relevant snippet from https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/range.c

```
...
if (beg < 0) {
beg += len;
if (beg < 0)
    goto out_of_range;
}
if (err == 0 || err == 2) {
if (beg > len)
    goto out_of_range;
if (end > len)
    end = len;
}
...
```

Here, if starting index `beg` is smaller than -length, it returns out of range `Qnil`. Otherwise, if starting index is larger than length of array (`len` in code snippet), it returns out of range (`Qnil`) too. NOTICE here, it's larger than not larger or equal than, that's why you get `[]` for `array[4,0]` (although 4 is out of range) but `nil` for `array[5,0]`