# Ruby Koans - about_arrays.rb

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm working on the about_arrays.rb file within Ruby Koans and I noticed this piece of code and I'm not sure why the answer is what it is:

```
def test_slicing_arrays
  array = [:peanut, :butter, :and, :jelly]

  assert_equal [], array[4,0]
  assert_equal [], array[4,100]
  assert_equal nil, array[5,0]
end
```

Based on the output for Ruby Koans, can someone explain to me why `array[4,0]` would evaluate to `[]` while `array[5,0]` evaluates to `nil?`.  Why wouldn't `array[5,0]` also evaluate to `[]`?

Out of curiosity, I tried `array[6,0]`, `array[7,0]`, and so on and also got nil.  Is there something special that Ruby does for the array index next in line to get something appended to it?

---

EDIT:

I found "[Array slicing in Ruby: looking for explanation for illogical behaviour (taken from Rubykoans.com)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568222/array-slicing-in-ruby-looking-for-explanation-for-illogical-behaviour-taken-fr?rq=1)", which asks the same question, but I'm still not understanding how indices work in array slicing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The s[n, 0] defines a place just before or after a character, and
>   often before one and after another.

[Source](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/380637).

The first *argument* to the slice is the lower bound. When it's `4`, it is still part of the array, just pointing to the very end. When the lower bound is beyond the length of the array, it's always `nil`.

It's best to think of the offsets of the spaces between the element values.

[RubyFiddle](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/1f69e).

Comment: Why would the lower bound be 4?  Aren't the array indices from 0 to 3?

Comment: @WillsonMock indexes != slice boundaries. See the link.

Comment: Sorry, this still isn't clear to me yet. When you're referring to boundaries in arrays, are you not referring to the first and last indicies of the array?

Comment: @WillsonMock I just added a RubyFiddle to help explain it. When you slice from `3,4`, you're getting the last element in that array, so you can see that `4` is a valid boundary. So if you start the slice at `4`, you're pointing to the end of the array, and slicing `0` elements from there will get you back an empty array. 

Someone might have a better way of explaining it than me. :)

Comment: @WillsonMock *"Empty slice"* serves for insertion instead of replacement when Array as l-value expression. So `array[4,0]=object` **inserts** object *after* the the last element, `array[3,0]=object` would insert object *before* the last element etc. Non-empty slice would **replace** elements.

Comment: @alex the empty slice always defines a place *before* the starting index, so the place after the last element has to be indexed with *(index of last element + 1)*.