# String#split strange behavior

Tags: ruby

I observed a strange behavior of the `split` method on a `String`.

```
"1..2".split('..')      # => ['1', '2']
"1..2".split('..', 2)   # => ['1', '2']

"..2".split('..')       # => ['', '2']
"..2".split('..', 2)    # => ['', '2']
```

Everything like expected, but now:

```
"1..".split('..')       # => ['1']
"1..".split('..', 2)    # => ['1', '']
```

I would expect the first to return the same that the second.

Does anyone have a good explanation, why `"1..".split('..')` returns an array with just one element? Or is it an inconsistency in Ruby? What do you think about that?

Comment: Which ruby do you use?

Comment: You can take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568222/array-slicing-in-ruby-looking-for-explanation-for-illogical-behaviour-taken-fr

Comment: @Mattherick: Same behavior in REE and Ruby 2.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Ruby String](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-split) documentation for `split`:

*If the limit parameter is omitted, trailing null fields are suppressed.*

Regarding the `limit` parameter, the Ruby documentation isn't totally complete. Here is a little more detail:

- If `limit` is positive, `split` returns at most that number of fields. The last element of the returned array is the "rest of the string", or a single null string ("") if there are fewer fields than `limit` and there's a trailing delimiter in the original string.

Examples:

```
"2_3_4_".split('_',3)
=> ["2", "3", "4_"]

"2_3_4_".split('_',4)
=> ["2", "3", "4", ""]
```

- If `limit` is zero [not mentioned in the documentation], `split` appears to return all of the parsed fields, and no trailing null string ("") element if there is a trailing delimiter in the original string. *I.e.*, it behaves as if `limit` were not present. (It may be implemented as a default value.)

Example:

```
"2_3_4_".split('_',0)
=> ["2", "3", "4"]
```

- If `limit` is negative, `split` returns all of the parsed fields and a trailing null string element if there is a trailing delimiter in the original string.

Example:

```
"2_3_4".split('_',-2)
=> ["2", "3", "4"]

"2_3_4".split('_',-5)
=> ["2", "3", "4"]

"2_3_4_".split('_',-2)
=> ["2", "3", "4", ""]

"2_3_4_".split('_',-5)
=> ["2", "3", "4", ""]
```

It would seem that something a little more useful or interesting could have been done with the negative `limit`.

Comment: Interesting, but why "1..".split("..", 3) is ["1", ""] and not ["1", "", ""]? (ruby 1.9.2p290)

Comment: Okay, but if `"..2".split('..')` is `['', '2']` and not `[nil, '2']`, why is `"1..".split('..')` then `['1', nil]` (and then `nil` ommitted) and not `['1', '']`?

Comment: @spickermann that's the way they chose to implement it. The text doesn't say `nil` it says "null" which, generically, is "empty" (`''`).

Comment: @Mattherick that's an interesting implementation detail which is unspecified in the documentation. For a positive `limit`, it only indicates that "at most" that many fields will be supplied. An even more interesting question is: Why does a negative limit provide no limit to the number of fields selected and does not suppress the single null value? A limit of `0` already produces all of the fields with no trailing null, and a positive limit provides the single null if there's a trailing delimiter. So why not use a negative limit as a means of providing all of the nulls? A Ruby library quirk. :)