# Slicing of arrays in ruby returns different result - nil vs. empty array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm puzzled by the fact that, if an array is sliced at it `length`, it returns an empty array, but at a length greater than that, it returns `nil`. What is the reason for this? For example:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Doing this, where `y > arr.length` and `x` is any positive integer, returns `nil`:

```
arr[y, x] # => nil
```

but doing the following returns `[]`

```
arr[5, x] # => []
```

Since `arr[5]` doesn't exist, shouldn't it return `nil` as well?

Comment: You seem to be expecting the outcome of: `arr[5..x]`

Comment: I am expecting a nil in the first case, because `arr[5]` isn't there.

Comment: @ansh0l: `arr[5]` isn't there, but `arr[5, 1]` is. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array slicing in Ruby: looking for explanation for illogical behaviour (taken from Rubykoans.com)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568222/array-slicing-in-ruby-looking-for-explanation-for-illogical-behaviour-taken-fr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all in the documentation: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D

> Additionally, an empty array is returned when the starting index for an element range is at the end of the array.
>
> Returns nil if the index (or starting index) are out of range.

Comment: In `arr[5]`, 5 is out of index right?
if yes, then that should return a nil, and not a new array.

Comment: I also came across this on ruby koans! Thanks!

Comment: I think this link explains it fine (from comments in that answer) - http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/380637