# array[array.size..-1] doesn't return nil

Tags: ruby, arrays

I noticed a strange behavior when `Range` are used as `Array` subscript. (At least it's strange for me.)

```
a = [1,2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
a[3]
=> nil
a[3..-1]
=> []
a[4]
=> nil
a[4..-1]
=> nil
```

I thought `a[3..-1]` returns `nil`, but somehow it returns `[]`. `a[-3..-4]` also returns `[]`.

Could anyone explain why it returns `[]`, when I use marginal values of range?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array slicing in Ruby: looking for explanation for illogical behaviour (taken from Rubykoans.com)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568222/array-slicing-in-ruby-looking-for-explanation-for-illogical-behaviour-taken-fr)

Answer (score 4):

Because when `range.begin == array.length`, it always returns `[]`. This is noted as a "special case" in [the Ruby documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D):

```
a = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" ]
# special cases
a[5]                   #=> nil
a[6, 1]                #=> nil
a[5, 1]                #=> []
a[5..10]               #=> []
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice there is a note in the documentation. May I ask why this case are treated as special?

Comment: @Tetsu, it's just a convenience, to allow you to do certain things more easily. For example, suppose you wanted to write a method `m` that returned an array containing the last `n` elements of a given array, for `0 <= n <= arr.size`. You could write `def m(arr,n) arr[arr.size-n..-1] end`, without having to treat `n = 0` as a special case. Ruby is littered with such special cases, all to make your life easier and better. The Ruby monks really do have your interest at heart.

Comment: Ah, now I understand why is it. Thanks!