# Ruby slicing not nil

Tags: ruby

For a four-element array, `[4]` returns `nil`, but `[4, 0]` returns an empty array.

```
array = [:peanut, :butter, :and, :jelly]
array[4] # => nil 
array[4, 0] # => [] 
array[5] # => nil 
array[5, 0] # => nil
```

Why would `[4, 0]` not return `nil` just like `[5, 0]`?

Answer from Array slicing in Ruby: looking for explanation for illogical behaviour (taken from Rubykoans.com) =>
[Graphical Explination of WHats Happening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568222/array-slicing-in-ruby-looking-for-explanation-for-illogical-behaviour-taken-fr/3568281#3568281)

Answer (score 3):

It's a special case. From the [official docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-slice) (the italics are mine):

> For start and range cases the starting index is just
>   before an element. *Additionally, an empty array is returned when the
>   starting index for an element range is at the end of the array.*

```
a = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" ]
# ...
# special cases
a[5]                   #=> nil
a[6, 1]                #=> nil
a[5, 1]                #=> []
```