# What is the purpose of the added trailing index in Ruby arrays?

Tags: ruby

I'm stuck trying to understand the following:

```
%w[a b c d][4,20] => []
%w[a b c d][4] => nil
%w[a b c d][5,20] => nil
```

1. Why is there the added index on the tail end of the Array?
2. Why does slice return different results?  Is 4 not out of range?  Seems inconsistent, but I think #1 will shed a bit of light on the answer to this question.

Comment: Read the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D), Luke! Difference between `ar[4]` and `ar[4,1]` from your example is also mentioned there (as a special case).

Comment: Thanks.  I need to brush up on my C.  I understand that it's a special case, but don't understand why or the purpose of it.  Why is ar[4,1] in range, but not ar[5,1].  The latter makes sense to me, the former does not.

Comment: I guess Matz thinks it makes sense. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3219311/357743) explanation. Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3568281/357743) one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly as KL-7 said, passing the index (or starting index for a slice) as one past the end of the array is treated as a special case. A slice starting at one past the last element will always return `[]`.

I don't think there is a purpose for this, seems to be just a side effect of how the `rb_ary_subseq` function within Ruby is coded (it does a `start > len` check instead of a `start >= len`).